# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filehash' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import hashlib
import sys

def dup_fileremove(dir):

    duplicate = []
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            filehash = md5.md5(file(filename).read()).hexdigest()
        if filehash not in duplicate:
            duplicate.append(filehash)
        else:
            os.remove(filename)
            print("removed : ", filename)

dup_fileremove("/tmp")
```

Let me know where I am wrong

Comment: you are calling filehash before it is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your starting filename is not a file , then you would not have a filehash variable , but even in that case you go onto check if filehash is in duplicate list , which causes your issue .

Another issue is that you do not reset filehash during each iteration , which can cause issue if you get directories in the list , and that would cause you to delete them , as filehash would be the previous filehash.

And another suggestion is to use set() instead of list of duplicates , as searching in set is faster.

Example -

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import hashlib
import sys

def dup_fileremove(dir):

    duplicate = set()
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        filehash = None
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            filehash = md5.md5(file(filename).read()).hexdigest()
        if filehash not in duplicate:
            duplicate.add(filehash)
        else:
            os.remove(filename)
            print("removed : ", filename)

dup_fileremove("/tmp")
```

Comment: Sure Anand i will take care of this

Answer (score 2):

In case `filename` is not a file `filehash` variable won't be created

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `filehash` before it was even assigned

```
duplicate.append(filehash)
```

That is `filehash` may not be created since in is assigned in a `if` case:

```
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    filehash = md5.md5(file(filename).read()).hexdigest()
```

what you could do is

```
def dup_fileremove(dir):
    filehash =None #Create filehash variable
    duplicate = []
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
           filehash = md5.md5(file(filename).read()).hexdigest()
        if filehash and filehash not in duplicate: #Check if file hash is not None
           duplicate.append(filehash)
        else:
           os.remove(filename)
           print("removed : ", filename)

dup_fileremove("/tmp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Working script:

> Blockquote

```
#!/usr/bin/python import os import hashlib import sys

def dup_fileremove(dir):
    duplicate = set()
    path=os.getcwd()
    print ("The dir is: ", path)
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        filehash = None
        filepath=os.path.join(dir, filename)
        print("Current file path is: ", filepath)
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            filehash =hashlib.md5(file(filepath).read()).hexdigest()
        if filehash not in duplicate:
            duplicate.add(filehash)
        else:
            os.remove(filepath)
            print("removed : ", filepath)

dup_fileremove("/tmp")
```